# Logic hole with negative numbers in isALeapYear condition in java

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement, leap-year

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean year = isLeapYear(9999);
    System.out.println("Is Leap Year: " + year);
}
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
    int rem4 = year % 4;
    int rem100 = year % 100;
    int rem400 = year % 400;
    if ((year >= 1 && year <= 9999) && (rem4 == 0) && (rem100 == 0 && rem400 == 0) || (rem100 != 0) && (rem4 == 0)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I enter a negative year (so far only -1024) my range condition doesn't work.
But if I enter any other negative leap year it works(-2020). So I don't know what I'm possibly missing, or if the structure of the algorithm is quite right. Any help will be appreciated.

What is expected is that when I enter a year that is not a leap year, and if it is a negative leap year, it returns false.

Comment: The crux of the issue is that last `|| (rem100 != 0 && rem4 == 0)`. Since the other clauses before it are `&&`, this one is treated as a OR against the _entire_ clause. `-1024 % 100 != 0` is true, as well as `-1024 % 4 == 0`, so the OR satisfies the whole `if`. The boolean logic in that `if` needs a little work.

Comment: Did you maybe set your parenthesis wrong? Because having `((` at the start and `))` at the very end doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You might es well just use a single parenthesis in this case, because putting an extra parenthesis around your whole expression doesn't do anything.

Comment: Consider moving each condition to a private method to simplify the overall joining of all of the conditions.

Comment: There's really no such thing as a negative leap year.  How would people have known that it was a multiple of 4 years until the birth of Jesus?

Comment: Well, technically [there never was a leap year before 1582](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Leap_day). The last few statements under "Algorithm" (before "Leap Day") also address projecting this algorithm to earlier years, but you'll end up down the temporal rabbit hole if you go too far.

Comment: Remove the parentheses and add the positive validation to the other section of the if, solves the logic hole. I wanted to include the exception of hundreds, etc, so that there are no leap years left out, that only fulfill part of the rule. Really dont know why a negative leap year, if there is any information at your fingertips I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Rogue It's not true that there was never a leap year before 1582.  The very page that you linked to includes this text.  _"... by AD 8 the leap years were being observed every fourth year ..."_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure, but maybe it's because when
`|| (rem100 != 0) && (rem4 == 0))` returns a `true` statement, your whole function returns `true`, negating the whole first part of your if-statement.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's considered cool to be concise and all, but this kind of thing is often best done with multiple simple conditionals. Especially when you're first developing it.

```
if (year < 1 || year > 9999)
    return false;
if (rem4 != 0)
    return false;
if (rem100 == 0 && rem400 != 0)
    return false;
return true;
```

Or, perhaps:

```
if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999)
    if (rem4 == 0) {
        if (rem100 == 0)
            return (rem400 == 0);
        return true;
    }
return false;
```

Either way will be easier to debug than one big long complicated `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As the || overrides the positive validation part, just add that same validation in the other part of the condition...

```
(year >= 1 && year <= 9999 && rem4 == 0 && rem100 == 0 && rem400 == 0 || year >= 1 && year <= 9999 && rem100 != 0 && rem4 == 0)
```